# Dojox's JsonRestStore loading the same thing several times

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using a lazy loading tree in a web app project; however, I've ran into some strange behavior. It seems a simple tree with just 3 levels causes 7 requests for the root structure. After looking at the official JRS tree test, I'm not sure whether this is normal or not.

Have a look at this example:
http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.1/dojo-release-1.6.1/dijit/tests/tree/Tree_with_JRS.html

When I visit it, my browser makes 5 requests for the root structure. My only question is why?

**Edit**: Worth mentioning is this doesn't happen with dojo 1.5 or below.

Here's what it looks like in the inspector (Chrome):
[image: Chrome Inspector]

Comment: Can you please expand and provide the header information for each of those requests. The answer will most likely be in the header information.

Comment: For my local server, I get these exact same headers on each request: https://skitch.com/oscarbroman/fier3/min-el
Same goes for the demo server.

Comment: Those headers look fine @Oscar Broman. I would advise asking in #dojo on freenode. kriszyp is actually currently connected, he might be able to suggest what is wrong. This might be a silly point to add, but you aren't telling your Lazyload tree to automatically expand are you?

Comment: The demo is set to expand automatically, my script isn't. Either way, I'll drop by IRC and see if I can find some help there!

Comment: Oscar, did you get an answer to this from the dojo guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found a solution to this problem, thanks to this post on dojo interest: [thisisalink](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/JsonRestStore-ForestStoreModel-and-too-many-requests-td3391258.html).

basically, with dojo 1.6 the dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel was extended with a few new hook-like functions (I guess because of the work done with the TreeGrid). One of these, `onSetItem` is called once a tree node is expanded (thus going form preLoaded to fully loaded when using a lazyLoading store). In the basic implementation, this function calls `_requeryTop()`, which requeries all root items.

for our application we could simply replace `dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel` with our implementation `digicult.dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel`, where `onSetItem` and `onNewItem` don't call `this._requeryTop`.

Sadly it's not enough to subclass the ForestStoreModel, as there are `this.inherited(arguments);` calls in the functions which can't be replaced easily, so we had to copy the whole class (copy class, rename, comment out two lines - easiest fix in a long time :-) ) - this may force us to redesign the class again once we update dojo to an even newer version.

Comment: Thank you! I had my own little awkward way to fix this, which basically was adding a different 'id' entry to the lazy loaded leaf. That lead to lots of extra work, though..

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced the performance problems with dijit Tree when having a tree with 10000+ nodes to be all loaded at once, with ~3000 items at the very top level.
The tree had only one dummy root node which loads the whole tree on the first click via ajax call.

In this case the tree creation took more than 1 minute to load and I got 'Stop running this script' dialog popup on IE8.

After applying a few optimization steps, the tree now loads within 2 seconds on all major browsers (IE8-IE11 included).

The first optimization I made was using `dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel` as the tree's model and `dojo/store/Memory` as the data store.

This speeded up inserting the ajax response json nodes into the tree's data store.

The second optimization concerned the slow creation of the Tree's nodes. That took more efforts to fix:

I had to extend `dijit/Tree` and override the `setChildItems()` function (the part of it which calls `_createTreeNode()` function).

I kept the whole logic of the `setChildItems()` intact, just added  parallelization of creating the tree nodes using this technique:

http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/Guido/post/2010/03/04/How-to-prevent-Stop-running-this-script-message-in-browsers.aspx

Hope it helps, if needed, I can post the source code of my workaround