# Dynatree or Jquery UI Dialog slowing down after couple thousand members

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dynatree

I have a simple application where I am displaying the tree list in a dialog box for the users to pick and have a little servlet in background for lazy loading. The problem happens for me when I click on one of the directories. This directory contains 4000+ other directories. The scroll bar becomes very hard to scroll down, slowing down measurably.

I have a solution to group things on the screen so that the users see the first couple characters of the directories and then slowly let them drill down. I was wondering if there is a simpler solution to this other than this thing I have in mind.

Comment: Do the users know which directory they are looking for? Maybe allow for some kind of filtering (either by exclusion or inclusion) of the directories listed.

Comment: Yes they do. I am implementing a little firstElement .. lastElement when displaying. The directories are basically numbers and I am sorting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have done is actually similiar to this. I have created a pseudo hirearchy where none existed before. See this answer for an other question. [How to render a large tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791806/dijit-tree-how-to-improve-performance-for-a-large-tree-with-500-child-nodes-und)